# Symfony 2.2 - no request scope in Voter

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to migrate from Symfony 2.1 to version 2.2.1. I use my own voter for deciding if user is granted to access given route. Voter is really simple and It worked before the update.
The problem is the voter needs request service to get a parameters which is required to check if user can access site (it is some id given in route, e.g. /profile/show/{userId}).
I always check if request scope is active to prevent error when using CLI or PHPUnit:

```
$this->request = null;
if ($container->isScopeActive('request')) {
  $this->request = $container->get('request');
}
```

And later throw an exception if there is no request in Vote method:

```
if ($this->request === null) {
  throw new \RuntimeException("There's no request in ProfileVoter");
}
```

I got this exception after every Vote calling (= on every page of my app).

EDIT: It happens only in dev environment.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the request scope? See also: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Comment: I'm sure that I'm not in the request scope (that's why I got the exception), but I don't know why. I can't use _scope=request_ in my Voter service definition because Security service doesn't use this scope I think. I've made no changes after updating Symfony it's dependencies.

Comment: Did you read the link? It talks about 3 ways to fix it, one of them should work

Comment: Yes, I read it;) It says: _a service cannot depend on services from a narrower scope_. So I can't change scope of my Voter because "security.access.decision_manager.delegate" references it. When I do this I get ScopeWideningInjectionException.

Comment: just scroll down a bit and read: "Using a Service from a narrower Scope¶"

Comment: Well, this situation would be different, I would not use service from the narrower scope, but service from wider scope (which I couldn't change) would use my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According do the Symfony2.2 documentation:

"Take care not to store the request in a property of the object for a future call of the service as it would cause the same issue described in the first section (except that Symfony cannot detect that you are wrong)." ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#using-a-service-from-a-narrower-scope )

In your solution, you check the container scope activity the in constructor, and if you have active scope, store it in $this->request. 
However, the correct approach is to store not request, but container itself:

```
protected $container;
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

An later, in your method (as you see, not in the constructor), check the scope activity:

```
public function vote(...)
{
    if ($this->container->isScopeActive('request')) {
      $request = $this->container->get('request');
    } else {
      throw new \RuntimeException("There's no request in ProfileVoter");
    }
}
```